# apk file name change

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Running MacOSX.  Updated to latest Android SDK and ADT.  Using Eclipse to deploy the apk files for my project.  Somehow, when the device attempts to launch an associated apk file it is appending a -1 to the /data/app path.  I suspect the problem is in Eclipse since this happens even when loading for the first time on a brand new AVD.  I have looked at the other solutions on this board including: the uncheck skip packaging and clean and rebuild.  Also tried a factory reset on the device just in case something was getting hung up.  In addition I thought I would be a clever monkey and change my project name and add the -1; not so clever. Android then went looking for the -2 version of the apk.  Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: All apps , without exception, have the "-1" (or -2 in some cases) appended to the apk in the "/data/app/" folder. Is removing this append somehow important? It does nothing to the apps performance. And my observation above, is on a device and not on an emulator.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for the info.  Okay.  Well the issue is that when I run my main app, it cannot find the sub app.  Which I assumed was because of the -1.  So something else is going on.  It does appear to be Eclipse related, though, since I can build and deploy from my WinXP 64-bit VM.

Comment: Well, not sure what this issue is. Never used eclipse on a Mac personally. Perhaps you could create another post and see where that gets you. The "-1" or "-2" certainly isn't a problem. It's just Android's way of storing a users installed app apk's I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem of your Intent.

Check if you had added your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When you want to making new activity, you should register it in your AndroidManifest.xml.